# Finding the area of a region?

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions, radicals

I sketched out the graph to get this figure but I can't seem to find the area of the shaded region... would one Y = 4 and the other Y = 8? [image]

I, in all honesty, am so flabbergasted with this question, any guidance will be much appreciated. I got 28/3 for the first integral (0 to 4) and 292/3 for the second integral (4 to 16)... I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Okay, I'm going to be honest, can someone please solve this for me? I got 320/3 as my final answer and yet it's still wrong, I'm just about given up at this point, it's literally my last question of this semester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want,

$$\left(\int_{0}^{4} \sqrt{x}\,\,dx-\int_{0}^{4}\dfrac12x\,\,dx\right)+\left(\int_{4}^{16}\dfrac12x\,\,dx-\int_{4}^{16}\sqrt{x}\,\,dx\right)$$

where the first term two terms give the area from $0$ to $4$ and the second term gives it from $4$ to $16$.

The expression becomes: $\left(\dfrac23x^{3/2}-\dfrac14x^2\right)\left.\right|_0^4+\left(\dfrac14x^2-\dfrac23x^{3/2}\right)\left.\right|_4^{16}$

Comment: Okay, I got 16/5 for the first integral and 1072/15 for the second, after making the first 48/15, I added it to the second to get 1120/15, it's still not correct. I am utterly confused.

Comment: @HarryJohnson According to my calculation, the area from $0$ to $4$ is $\dfrac43$ and from $4$ to $16$ is $\dfrac{68}3$, which gives a total of $24$.

Comment: AHHH, I GOT IT! I'm so silly, I was inputting it all wrong, I finally understand. The answer I got was 288/12... otherwise known as 24 :)))

Thank you so, so, so much!

Answer (score 7):

**HINT** Find the point of intersection, set the limits $a = 0$ and $b =$ the point you found, set up the integral with those limits and the function $f(x) - g(x)$, and set up another integral from $b$ to $16$ with $g(x) - f(x)$.

Comment: I got 28/3 for the first integral (0 to 4) and 292/3 for the second integral (4 to 16).. but it's not correct :(

Comment: @Harry: Can you write down your attempt at a solution in "Add another answer"? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I'm a novice, I have no idea where that is lol. But if it's not inconveniencing you that much, is the answer 320/3?

Comment: @HarryJohnson: I haven't worked out the problem. The button "Add another answer" is below, near the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up two double integrals.

The first one:

$\int_0^4 \int_{.5x}^ \sqrt{x} dydx$

The second one:

$\int_4^{16} \int_\sqrt{x}^{.5x} dydx$

The computation is straightforward.

Comment: Nice way to do it with double integrals.

Comment: Should the integral limits not be 0 to 4 and 4 to 16, as the point of intersection is at $x=4$?

Comment: @GuyCorrigall you're right! My bad, it's hard to see the tick marks without my glasses. i'll fix that.

Comment: Okay I am still a bit confused, I don't know how to find the area? :(

Comment: @HarryJohnson what do you mean? You find the area through integration. A double integral is the same as a single integral, just iterated once more.

Comment: @Lame-Ov2.0 so would that mean it's 28/3 for the first integral (0 to 4) and 292/3 for the second integral (4 to 16)... I feel like I'm doing this wrong. And do I subtract now? to get 264/3?

Comment: Since you want the area of the shaded region, and each double integral is set up to find the first and second shaded region respectively, you add them to find the total area of the entire shaded region.

Comment: I got 320/3 after adding but that still is wrong

Answer (score 2):

The area between two curves given by functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is given by,

$$ \int_a^b \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert dx = \int_a^b \textbf{Top Function} - \textbf{Bottom Function }\mathrm{d}x$$

A common mistake students make when trying to compute this is that they don't change the order of the subtraction when the "Top Function" changes from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. This happens whenever the two curves cross eachother. In your case they seem to cross at $x=4$ so that you need to evaluate an integral from $0$ to $4$ and then another one from $4$ to $16$ always making sure to have to top function come first in the subtraction.

Comment: is it 4 to 15, or 4 to 16?

Comment: @Harry Johnson 4 to 16, made a mistake when looking at the diagram.

Comment: Mr. Spencer, can you help me solve this problem? I'm just about given up at this point. I got 320/3 after adding both my integrals and yet it's still wrong.

Comment: @Harry: If you can display your work by clicking the "Add Another Answer" page at the bottom, we will be glad to help you.